# Can't set background color of UITableViewCell in IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have created a bunch of cells which I reuse in a table view. All of those cells just have different `UILabel`s inside them and some `UIImageView`s (nothing covers the complete cell).

Setting the background color in IB has no effect (always white or transparent, can't say which one of them). But if I press Command-R (simulate interface) the cell has the correct background color in the simulator.

I tried to set it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but it doesn't work like I would think either.

This does the trick:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

but these have no effect (even if I set the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` to `clearColor`):

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I set all the layout/font/background stuff in IB. Any idea why this isn't working in this case?

Why do I need to modify the `contentView`'s `backgroundColor` and not the `backgroundView`'s?

It seems to be a common issue. Could somebody please point me in the right direction to (finally) understand how background colors are handled within a table view cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier solution:  When you create a `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder, simply drag and drop an additional `UIView` so that it covers the entire `UITableViewCell` you're creating within IB.  Place your additional UI elements on top of this additional `UIView`. You can set this extra `UIView` to whatever background you like.

There are quite a few answers on StackOverflow that suggest you change the background color of your `UITableViewCell` by using a line of code like this one:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you add a drop shadow to your cell by adjusting the `contentView`'s frame size slightly, you may find that this line will change both the background color of your cell and the color of your drop shadow area as well.

Answer (score 53):

To change the background color of the cell, you have to do it in the `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.  This is mentioned in the [UITableViewCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell) near the bottom of the Overview.  So you need:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
}
```

The contentView is just the recommended subview to put custom controls in so that the cell gets layed out properly when table editing is going on.

Comment: thx for the info. but still, why is the setting in the IB not working? i set just the label.text in the controller. and setting the background IB works in all nib's (UIView), but not with UITableViewCell.

Comment: Not able to confirm at this time but UITableViewCell seems to be a special case.  In the Apple docs for willDisplayCell and custom cells, it mentions to use this method which is called "after the table view is done setting colors based on selection, etc".  It may work if you create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell in code but not able to check it right now.

Comment: ok, so i just set it up in code. thx for your most excellent help.

Comment: You can now simply set cell.contentView.backgroundColor instead, e.g. in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: ...but note: bugs in Xcode5, if you set the color in InterfaceBuilder, Xcode5 disables the entire color system for table rows. Stupid.

Comment: good answer thanks. Can confirm that setting this attribute still doesn't work in IB as of Xcode 7.0.1. Apple should just remove it if it has no effect