# is this code OK for setting UITableViewCell background color?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, background-color

I've read quite a few different ways to tackle the problem of setting the UITableViewCell color.  Was just after a quick confirmation that the code/approach below is fine re a best practice / performance point of view?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Some notes/questions associated with this:

1. Would this be the best re performance in the sense that it seems like this code will be called quite a lot?  i.e. as opposed to if the background color was just set once for the cell design, say in IB (which I know doesn't quite work) [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166747/why-doesnt-uitableviewcell-background-color-work-set-in-interface-builder)
2. I see some sample code that loops through the various sub-views of a cell to set them, but this wouldn't normally be required?  I've tried this code above and it seemingly works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, this is the way to do it. The `UITableViewCell` documentation even explicitly states that background colors should be set in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` as opposed to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Don't fear, you are on the right path sir.