# TableCellView with custom xib not loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Have have created a child of `UITableViewCell`, `MenuItem` which contains functionality for my custom table cell. I have also created a xib-file with a custom cell and set the `UITableViewCell` in the xib-file to have the class `MenuItem`. The name of the xib-file is `MenuItem` as well. In my `UITableViewController` class I'm doing this in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
UINib *menuItems = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MenuItem" bundle:nil];
[[self tableView] registerNib:menuItems forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MenuItem"];
```

But the background color used in the xib-file isn't used in the cells the table displays. If I add a new label, it shows up, but the background color is just plain white. Does anyone know why?

EDIT: I do use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MenuItem"];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Check out this link MAy be It will help you...


   [enter link description here][1] and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166747/why-doesnt-uitableviewcell-background-color-work-set-in-interface-builder

Comment: Thanks, found my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sudha for links to the answer.

It turns out you can't set the background color in the xib-file. You have to do it in the willDisplayCell of the delegate. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html, outlined box close to the top.