# Using the UITableViewCell background color from a nib

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nib

In Xcode, I have UITableViewCell nib which holds a label, and in the nib I customized colors for both the UITableViewCell background and the label text background color.
When the table displays, the label's text displays in the specified color, but the cell's background color does not; rather the background color of the UITableView nib is what shows as each cell's background.
Why? Is the cell background color attribute being ignored or overridden at some point?

Answer (score 0):

1. http://pegolon.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/using-uitableviewcell-with-interfacebuilder/
2. [Can't set background color of UITableViewCell in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140794/cant-set-background-color-of-uitableviewcell-in-ib)

May be these link will help you

Comment: Thanks but the links don't address the question. I'm not asking HOW to set the cell's background, rather WHY this "natural" approach of setting it in the cell's nib doesn't work.

Comment: Same approach is working fine in my app. So i think  in your app there are some connection problem in outlets.

Comment: Good to hear it works sometimes. The app is a sample app from a book, and it's working, except if I change the bg color in the cell's nib, nothing happens, and if I change the bg color in the table-view the color does change, as it does when I change both.