# UITableViewCell not showing background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am loading a cell from a xib directly using code below but the problem is background color of the cell is not showing even i had set in xib and i am also setting it through code. Can any guide me about the problem.

**I want to know why it is not showing the background color set in xib**

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GameCell123";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewTemp dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *array=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if (array !=nil && [array count]>0) 
    {
        cell=[array objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [cell setAccessoryView:[cell viewWithTag:3]];
    [(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:assessoryButtonCellSubviewTag] addTarget:self action:@selector(teamsAccessoryButtonTap:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // seting teams button as accessory view; 
}
```

Comment: Please, refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140794/cant-set-background-color-of-uitableviewcell-in-ib

Comment: o thanks yar. I searched but unfortunately i did not found that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As graver indicated, change the background color in the willDisplayCell delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];  
}
```